# Optimizing vectorized code for graph adjacency

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, matrix, graph-theory

I am writing some Machine Learning code in MATLAB, and I am representing a graph with an adjacency matrix A, and a clustering of the graph with a matrix Z defined in the following ways.

A: a_ij is 1 if there is an edge between node i, and node j. 0 otherwise.
Z: z_ij is 1 if node j is in cluster i. 0 otherwise.

I am computing a matrix N, which is the number of edges between clusters, defined in the following way:

N: n_ij is the number of edges between nodes in cluster i and nodes in cluster j. n_ii is the number of edges inside cluster i.

N can be computed by:

```
N = zAz'
```

where z' is z-transposed.

If I have a lot of nodes, then computing this takes some time, but that is not the problem. The problem is, that I move the nodes from cluster to cluster a lot of times, and each time I want to compute N.

So the problem is the following: Given that I know N, and that I then move node i from cluster c_1 to cluster c_2, how can I update N in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go from Z to Z + U, update

> N ← N + Z(AU') + (UA)Z' + UAU'
>   Z ← Z + U.

Z and U (and A, if it makes sense for your graph) should have sparse representations. In theory, at least, this does more or less *in compiled code* what I would do in C: scan the neighbors of i, decrementing the edge counts to and from i's old cluster and incrementing the edge counts to and from i's new cluster. In practice, you may need to transpose Z to get it to align with properly Matlab's sparse matrix representation and execute the update Z ← Z + U by replacing two whole rows so that the newly zeroed entries are not treated as nonzero.

Comment: I guess I forgot to state, that I sometimes need to create a new cluster, and that I sometimes need to remove clusters. How should I create U when constructing a new, or removing a cluster?

Comment: Add an empty cluster: add a zero row to Z and row/column to N. Delete an empty cluster: reverse this process. If you actually mean merging two clusters, there's a better way to update N than moving one vertex at a time (replace the two rows of Z with their sum, then replace the two rows then columns of N with their sum).